# Constant Objects

Tags: c++, object, constants

Define a class Shape and create constant object from the class with at least one constant data member. Create object in main function from the class Shape. Also display state of the constant object in main( ) function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
private:
    string color;
    const float radius;

public:
    Shape(string,float);

};

Shape:: Shape(string clr,float rad): radius(rad)
{
    color = clr;
    cout<<"The color of the  Shape(Circle) is : "<<clr<<endl<<"The radius is : "<<radius<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    const Shape sh("Red", 7.5);

    return 0;
}
```

Is the above code satisfying the question above it?

Comment: Pretty subjective, but you don't seem to be fulfilling the requirements of displaying "state" of the object "in the main function" -- that's just a side-effect of doing it in the constructor which is bad practice.  For more subjective advice, I would say: A) stop using `using namespace std;` B) use consistent spacing; C) break up multi-line outputs onto separate lines of code D) use class initializer list to init `color` too; E) you forgot to include `<string>`; F) if it's a circle, it should be called `Circle`, not `Shape`.

Comment: Okay, I'll make all the changes to make the code look better. But what is meant by "Display state of the constant object in main() function".

Comment: Re-order the sentence.... "in the main function, display the state of the constant object".  Seems like it's suggesting that you get data from that object and display it with calls to `std::cout` that are written in the main function, not in the constructor for Shape.

Comment: okay. I posted an answer. Can you check it?

Answer (score 1):

I would not print the output in the constructor, instead create a `print` function and then call it from main.

The constructor should initialize the object. The printing of it is something that is done from a user of that class, of from some function of the class, depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
private:
    string color;
    const float radius;
public:
    Shape(string,float);
    void Display(void)const;

};
Shape:: Shape(string clr,float rad):color(clr), radius(rad) {}

void Shape:: Display(void)const
{
    cout<< "The color is : "<<color<<endl;
    cout<< "The radius is : "<<radius<<endl;

}

int main()
{
    const Shape sh("Red",7.8);
    sh.Display();

    return 0;
}
enter code here
```